# Task-based fMRI dataset with very simple task (e.g. view stripes)

Tags: neuroscience, statistics, fmri, data

For my Bachelor thesis I need an fMRI dataset in order to look for causal relationships. I want to be able to confirm my work, so the causal relationships should already be known. Therefore, ideally the dataset would involve very simple visual tasks, like viewing vertical and horizontal stripes. It should have at least 20 Participants and 30 trials per task. It should also be randomized, so the participant doesn't know what they are going to see next. Does anyone have an idea? I've been searching forever and haven't even come close to a dataset which fulfills my criteria.